# SharePoint 2013 sites are down, found Event Viewer error message with Event ID 6398, SPLicenseRenewalJobDefinition error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem

All of sudden my SharePoint 2013 sites are stopped working one day, throwing errors instead of opening the site. Then I have looked into the Event Viewer logs and found that there is an error as below:

> "The execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPLicenseRenewalJobDefinition
>   threw an exception. More information is included below. Object
>   reference is not set to an instance of an object."

I have reset the SharePoint configuration cache but still, SharePoint sites did not work. Then I have restarted the SharePoint 2013 server and then all the sites are back to working state.

Please let me know what could be the cause of "SPLicenseRenewalJobDefinition" error and how to prevent this to happen in the future?

Thank You